# Add Google Authenticator to ASP.NET with Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I have found several articles on implementing Google Authenticator and each one specifies how to do so with "Individual User Accounts" authentication.  How does one implement Google Authenticator with "Windows Authentication"?

Comment: You can't. Windows Authentication uses Active Directory, Kerberos, LDAP, NTLM, and local Windows User accounts. None of those have any first-party support or integration with Google Authenticator.

Comment: There are third-party products that allow Google Authenticator to be used with Windows authentication, but they are only supported for local machine access ( https://www.rohos.com/2013/02/27/google-authenticator-windows-login/ ) - there is no support for them through ASP.NET or IIS.